# How can convert a field to uppercase in Qlikview and calculate the count based on the substring?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to convert a field values to upper case in qlikview

My Query is `SQL SELECT * FROM "mt_table";`

My result table is as follows,

[image]

I want to get the count of each Desc.

For eg: I want to get the count of Developers. Here Desc is entered manually. So it will not be same. Here i have to consider **'Joined as Developer', 'PROMOTED AS DEVELOPER', 'Promoted as developer'** - as Developer. I need to consider string only **'as devleoper'** also it should be case insensitive.

I tried as follows

```
Count({<SubStringCount(Upper(Desc), Upper('as developer')) > 0>}Desc)
```

But not working. For testing i just tried `Upper(Desc)` but it doesn't give anything. What is wrong with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same wildcard notation you use when selecting in list boxes in your set analysis to achieve this

```
count({<Desc={"*developer*">}Desc)
```